# support Toolbar upNavigator hiding problems

Tags: android, toolbar, animated

I made this issue:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=189760

basically when

```
 android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

Hiding up indicator hides makes it only invisible, not gone.

Full xml :

Program code:

```
public void updateToolbar(boolean show)
{
    if(getSupportActionBar() != null) {
        if(show) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        } else {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use below method for hide and remove up indicator space

`getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);`

Comment: Dose not work.  In fact  setDisplayShowHomeEnabled()  dose nothing.